# quickbooks purchase details

Tags: vb.net, qbfc

When doing a purchase in qb you would enter a bill against the item you are buying. My question is the following:
a. when using qbfc which component would be the correct one, i have tried the ibillquery, itranscationquery but cant seem to find the correct one.

```
Dim MsgRq As IMsgSetRequest
        MsgRq = sessMgr.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 4, 0)

    Dim bquery As IBillQuery
    bquery = MsgRq.AppendBillQueryRq
    bquery.ORBillQuery.RefNumberList.Add("")

    Dim MsgRs As IMsgSetResponse
    MsgRs = sessMgr.DoRequests(MsgRq)

    Dim resp As IResponse
    resp = MsgRs.ResponseList.GetAt(0) 

    Dim blist As IBillRetList
    blist = resp.Detail

    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To blist.Count - 1
        Dim bret As IBillRet
        bret = blist.GetAt(x)
        Console.Write(bret.ORItemLineRetList.GetAt(0).ItemLineRet.Desc.GetValue)
    Next
```

The above works well for retrieving the actual bill info bot not the underlying stock.

Answer (score 0):

Many purchasing transactions in QuickBooks can use items and/or expenses. It could be a Bill, Item Receipt, Check, or Credit Card. When you query for these transactions, you need to check if there is any ORItemLineRetList. If ORItemLineRetList is null, then there are no items on that transaction. The only purchasing transaction that only has items is a Purchase Order.

Each of the items in the ORItemLineRet, the item could be a ItemLineRet or a ItemGroupLineRet. For ItemLineRet you can access information about the item, like's it's name/list id, description, quantity, and cost.

Based on your code, I would do another loop through the ORItemLineRetList. The code may not be 100% as I don't use VB

```
Dim x as Integer
For x = 0 to blist.Count -1
    Dim bret as IBillRet
    bret = blist.GetAt(x)
    If bret.ORItemLineRetList IsNot Null
        For y = 0 to bret.ORItemLineRetList.Count -1
            Dim bItemLine as IORItemLineRet
            bItemLine = bret.ORItemLineRetList.GetAt(y)
            If bItemLine.ItemLineRet IsNot Null
                Console.Write(bItemLine.ItemLineRet.ItemRef.FullName.GetValue)
            End If
        Next
     End If
Next
```